# Storing User Credientials in the Bayeux Server

Tags: cometd, bayeux

I'd like to store the clients UserName and SessionId when a client subscribes to a particular channel. When i override canHandshake() i can get the user credentials using the following:

```
userName = (String) authentication.get("userName");
sessionId = (String) authentication.get("sessionId");
```

Just wondering how i can store these credentials and later retrieve them?  I've had a look at the authentication documentation [here](http://cometd.org/documentation/howtos/authentication) and it just mentions linking the authentication data to the session. Is this the Bayeux Server side session??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "linking" can be done in several ways.

You can link this information in an external map via:

```java
@Override
public boolean canHandshake(BayeuxServer server, ServerSession session, ServerMessage message)
{
    ...
    Map<String, Object> authentication = ...;
    map.put((String)authentication.get("userName"), session);
    ...
}
```

where the `map` can be a `java.util.ConcurrentHashMap<String, ServerSession>` field in the security policy itself, or in another object such as a user service.

For simpler use cases, the `userName` can be linked directly to the session in this way:

```java
session.setAttribute("userName", authentication.get("userName"));
```

Or you can use both techniques.

This is the [updated link](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/howtos/authentication) for the authentication how-to, and you can find the latest comprehensive CometD documentation at http://docs.cometd.org.